# Non-linear cyclic order of a field

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, field-theory, order-theory

A cyclic order of a group is *non-linear* if any cut of it is not compatible with the group operation.

A *cut* of a cyclically ordered set is a linear order $<$ such that

- $a < b < c \implies [a, b, c]$

for any elements $a$, $b$, $c$ of the set.

A cut of a cyclically ordered group is *compatible* with the group operation ($+$) iff:

- $a < b \implies a + x < b + x$ and $x + a < x + b$

for any elements $a$, $b$, $x$ of the group.

I am trying to find properties of a non-linear cyclic order on fields:

1. Is there an infinite field with a non-linear cyclic order on the additive group?
2. Is there a field with a non-linear cyclic order on the additive group such that $[0, 1, -1]$ and $[0, x, 1]$ for some element $x$?

Comment: I assume all elements z = -z are non-negative and non-positive.

Comment: The standard compatibility with addition is required.
Any compatibility with multiplication is optional.

Comment: If we are not requiring compatibility with multiplication, then there's little to no point in talking about rings or fields; the question should just ask about cyclically ordered abelian groups.

Comment: I don't believe cyclically orders are well-known; it would help if you give a definition of the term, and related terms. For example, what is a "nonnegative" element in this context? The term doesn't appear anywhere in Wikipedia's article.

Comment: 1. The compatibility with multiplication is not the same as for addition. It is adjusted to fit certain algebraic structures. I don't see any problems adjusting the compatibility for the strict cyclic order.

2. Nonnegative means not negative. The standard definition of a negative element a: $(0, -a, a)$.

Comment: "First order theory of cyclically ordered groups": https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.0499.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By picking any irrational real number $\alpha$, there is an injective map

$$ \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{T} : x \mapsto e^{2 \pi i \alpha x} $$

and thus (?) $\mathbb{Q}$ inherits a cyclic ordering from the one on $\mathbb{T}$. Since, in the comments, you say you only care about compatibility with addition, I imagine this serves as an example to both of your questions.

Comment: @AlexC: Typo fixed

Comment: Thanks a lot! Where can I read more about this type of fields (the map)?