# Is there an infinite set with a discrete cyclic order?

Tags: order-theory

Let's call a cyclic order of a set *discrete* if every *cut* of the order is a *jump*.

A *cut* of a cyclic order is a linear order $<$ such that $x < y < z \implies (x, y ,z)$ for any elements $x$, $y$, $z$ of the set.

A *cut* of a cyclic order is a *jump* if it has the least and the greatest elements.

Clearly, the induced cyclic order of integers is not *discrete* since the natural linear order of integers does not have the least and the greatest elements.

However, there are other ways of ordering integers cyclically, e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2196717/427611.

I am wondering if it is possible to find a *discrete* cyclic order of integers or maybe of some other infinite set.

If it is not possible, what would be the easiest way to prove that?

By cyclic order I mean a total strict cyclic order defined in here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_order#The_ternary_relation

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2557900/infinite-totally-ordered-set-with-all-non-empty-subsets-containing-both-endpoint, just stated in the language of cyclic orders instead of total orders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a cyclic order on $A$ and an element $a\in A$, we can define $<$ as
$$ x<y\iff [x,y,a]\lor x\ne y=a$$
(i.e., we "cut" immediately behind $a$). This obviously has $a$ as a maximal element. Assume that there is also a minimal element, no matter what $a$ we pick. Call it $S(a)$, and we have a successor map on $A$. By the same argument, we obtain a predecessor map and this is clearly inverse to the successor map. Using these (and picking an element $a_0\in A$) we can map $\iota\colon\Bbb Z\to A$ such that no elements of $A$ are between the images of consecutive integers.

If $\iota$ is not injective, then it must be periodic and so $\iota(\Bbb Z)$ finite. In that case $\iota$ must be onto because there is no way to "squeeze" any further elements of $A$ in-between. As we are interested in the case of infinite $A$, we can ignore this case. *[Thanks to a comment by Eric Wolsey]*

Now we can make a new cut "above $\Bbb Z$", i.e., we define
$$x\prec y\iff \exists n\in\Bbb Z\colon [x,y,\iota(n)]. $$
This does not have a maximal element.

Comment: Note that this tacitly uses the assumption that $A$ is infinite to conclude that $\iota$ is injective.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**. Let's show that every cut of a *discrete* cyclic order is *discrete*.
A linear order is *discrete* if every cut of it $(A, \overline A)$ is a *jump*.
A cut $(A, \overline A)$ of a linear order is a *jump* if $A$ has the greatest and $\overline A$ has the least element.

Assuming a cut $(A, \overline A)$ of a cut $<$ of a *discrete* cyclic order is not a *jump*.
Defining the new linear order $<_A$ in the following way:
$x <_A y$ if and only if

- $x \in \overline A \land y \in A$, or
- $x \in \overline A \land y \in \overline A \land x < y$, or
- $x \in A \land y \in A \land x < y$.

It is easy to check that $<_A$ is a cut of the cyclic order using the rule:
$(x, y, z) \iff x < y < z \lor y < z < x \lor z < x < y$.

If $A$ does not have the greatest element, then the cut $<_A$ does not have the greatest element.
If $\overline A$ does not have the least element, then the cut $<_A$ does not have the least element.
Therefore, if $(A, \overline A)$ is not a *jump* of $<$ then $<_A$ is not a jump of the cyclcic order.

**Step 2**. Any cut of an infinite *discrete* cyclic order is an infinite *discrete* linear order.
Any infinite *discrete* linear order is isomorphic to $\mathbb N$ or $\mathbb Z$.
Therefore, an infinite *discrete* cyclic order does not have any *jump*.